# IBM MQ queue activity

Tags: ibm-mq

Is it possible to check live traffic in a queue? (I mean if somebody put/get a msg in the queue , there should be an activity log, or something like that) Where it goes? where it came from?
Count the message number or any other alternate method?

For example:

Random APP1 put a message to a queue (Q.RND1)
Random APP2 get a message from (Q.RND1)

Could we live track the message (to - from) ?

Comment: Look at accounting and statistics for this.   You will need a program to read and format them. [MQEV](https://www.mqgem.com/mqev.html) from MQGem Software is one such product.   You could also look at a MQ API exit which can log activity like this.  [MQ Auditor](https://capitalware.com/mqa_overview.html) from Capitalware is a product that does this.

Comment: Also look into Application Activity Trace. See https://mqtechconference.com/sessions_v2017/MQTC_2017_Activity_Trace.pdf

Comment: Is it possible to handle it without any 3rd party software?